# DNS Unlocker Adware not getting removed from firefox with any tool or manually

Tags: firefox, dns, virus

This virus is giving me a hard time. It is showing popups and ads on my firefox. There is no program with this name or similar in:

```
1. Installed program list in windows 10
2. Not in firefox add ons
```

It is only showing ads in firefox.

```
I have tried:
1. Avira Antivirus free
2. Malwarebytes
3. AdwCleaner
4. Hitman pro
```

But none of these detected it.

An example of ad it is showing.
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have downloaded some MalWare crap. See

[Download.com and Others Bundle Superfish-Style HTTPS Breaking Adware](http://www.howtogeek.com/210265/download.com-and-others-bundle-superfish-style-https-breaking-adware/?PageSpeed=noscript).

It may help you in your situation.

Comment: It was quite userful information. But I considered it easier to install new windows instead following that.

Comment: @EresDev: Thanks. I read it today in the news. This crap can be devastating to your whole operating system's security. As suggested in the article, you chose the right way to reinstall your whole OS. If it turns out to be the best answer, I would appreciate you to accept my answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered DNS Unlocker pop-up ads a month ago and I found out that "DNS Unlocker" had modified my DNS settings. In fact, I googled on the web and found a post mentioned repairing DNS settings and it did the trick.

The path to do this follows:

- Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center >
  Change Adapter Settings.
- Right-click your active internet connection (usually Wi-Fi since
  everyone uses that, unless your using a desktop) and click
  properties.
- Now under the Networking tab, scroll down until you find Internet
  Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4). Highlight that then click on
  properties. Both options in this windows should be automatic. The
  first option should be set to "Obtain an IP address automatically"
  and the second should be set to "Obtain DNS server address
  automatically!".
- If your computer belongs to a company or you actually have a custom
  DNS, then this would not apply to you. Once you are done, click "OK"
  and close the windows. Now go back into Chrome and reset your
  settings one more time and boom, it should work just fine.